# Showing $L_v(df)=d(Vf)$, where $L$ is Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

> The Lie derivative is defined as:
> $$L_v(fX)=[V,fX]=(Vf)(X)+f[V,X]$$

> Show that $L_v(df)=d(Vf)$

Applying the formula straightforwardly:

$$L_v(df)(X)=V df(X)+df[V,X]=(Vdf)(X)+df(V(X)-X(V))=VdfX+df(V(X))-df(X(V))$$

I suspect that the first and last term would cut, but how do I justify that?

How do I handle $VdfX$?

**Question**:

Can someone help me solve and understand this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145922/discussion-on-question-by-pedro-gomes-showing-l-vdfdvf-where-l-is-lie); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.